# Distribuição de DLL

Tags: c#, .net, delphi, dll

Criei uma DLL COM em c# VS2010 para ser distribuída com outra aplicação em Delphi.

Esta DLL faz apenas consumo em WEB Services.

Na máquina onde foi construída a DLL não ocorre erro. Mas nas distribuição quando é executado os métodos da DLL é retornado a mensagem:

> O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado.

Isso é alguma configuração que deve ser executada na configuração da DLL?

**Código da DLL**

```
    public string RecepcionarLoteRps(string AEnderecoWebService, string AXmlEntrada)
    {
        string Retorno = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            ServiceReferenceAbrasfV201.nfseClient wsClient = new ServiceReferenceAbrasfV201.nfseClient("nfseSOAP1", AXmlEntrada);
            Retorno = wsClient.RecepcionarLoteRps(Cabecalho(), AXmlEntrada);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Retorno = e.Message;
        }
        return Retorno;
    }
```

Código em Delphi para enviar os parâmetros a dll.

```
var
  LClientWBAws: IAbrasfV201_Interface;
  LRetorno: string;
begin
    LClientWBAws := CoAbrasfV201.Create;
    if (Pos('ConsultarLoteRpsEnvio', LEnviaArqXml) > 0) then
    begin
      LRetorno := LClientWBAws.Getnfse(ALayout.Parametros['EnderecoWebService'], LEnviaArqXml);
    end
    else if (Pos('CancelarNfseEnvio', LEnviaArqXml) > 0) then
    begin
      LRetorno := LClientWBAws.CancelarNfse(ALayout.Parametros['EnderecoWebService'], LEnviaArqXml);
    end
    else
    begin
      LRetorno := LClientWBAws.RecepcionarLoteRps(ALayout.Parametros['EnderecoWebService'], LEnviaArqXml);
    end;

end;
```

Comment: Provavelmente você tem que colocar dentro da DLL o arquivo de configuração do webservice.

Comment: Mas isso já esta la as configurações dos WSDLs

Comment: Coloque mais informações sobre seu erro. Ocorre uma exceção? Para quem o erro ocorre?

Comment: A DLL é ActiveX?

Comment: Caramba pode ser tanta coisa, algumas coisas que pensei aqui:
- Verifique que a dll foi realmente distribuída e esta na pasta que a aplicação espera que ela esteja.
- Outra coisa que pode acontecer eh se sua dll tiver alguma referencia e essa referencia não estiver marcada para ser distribuída junto, então a sua dll esta indo, mas alguma dependência dela não. tem uma opção na referencia que diz "Copy Local"

Comment: O erro: : Processo concluído com erro - Erro técnico: O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado.

Comment: public string RecepcionarLoteRps(string AEnderecoWebService, string AXmlEntrada)
        {
            string Retorno = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                ServiceReferenceAbrasfV201.nfseClient wsClient = new ServiceReferenceAbrasfV201.nfseClient("nfseSOAP1", AXmlEntrada);
                Retorno = wsClient.RecepcionarLoteRps(Cabecalho(), AXmlEntrada);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Retorno = e.Message;
            }
            return Retorno;
        }

Comment: Foi importado como ActiveX no Delphi.

Comment: Me surgiu uma dúvida de última hora. Os arquivos .svcinfo e os WSDLs devem ser distribuídos junto com a DLL?

Comment: Se o único objetivo da DLL eh chamar esse serviço, porque não essa chamada direto no Delphi? O Delphi também consegue consumir web services.

Comment: Normalmente quando eu encontro um erro deste tipo eu uso o [ProcessMonitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) para descobrir qual arquivo está tentando ser acessado. 99% da vezes funciona.

Comment: Dê uma olhada na resposta que postei aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8107/dll-c-no-delphi-7/8341#8341

Answer (score 2):

Utilize o seguinte comando para registrar a DLL na máquina em que o arquivo não é encontrado:

```
regasm minhaDll.dll /tlb:minhaDll.tlb
```

Comment: Isso é executado na instalação.

Answer (score 0):

Eu achei esses dois post com informações.

1) Exclusivo para delpi [Exemplo em Delphi](http://www.infoconsultor.info/dll-c-para-delphi/comment-page-1/)

2) Para Magic XPA, porém a ideia é semelhante.
[Exemplo de Magic](http://blog.magicsoftware.com.br/integrando-unipaas-e-com-net/)

Passos:
1) No arquivo AssemblyInfo.Cs (dentro de properties) alterar o código abaixo para true

```
[assembly: ComVisible(true)]
```

2) Criar uma interface

```
[Guid("917979B5-2DC2-419C-A38F-46C23D01E587")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
public interface INota
{
    string EnviarNota(string chave);
}
```

3) Criar a implementação da classe.

```
[Guid("EDABAB76-CF5B-4674-BA94-925A7D811869")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
public class Nota : INota
{
    public string EnviarNota(string chave)
    {            
        return "Chave: " + chave;
    }
}
```

4) Vai nas propriedades do projeto > build > output > marca o check Register for COM interop

5) Criar um strong name, novamente propriedade do projeto > Sgning > marcar o check "Sing the assembly" > new > preencha os dados ... depois aparecerá um arquivo *.pfx na solução.

Feito isso a DLL está pronta para ser usada.

Agora é só registrar

1) Registrar no GAC use o comandano GacUtil /i nome_dll.dll

2) Registrar com o RegAsm :  regasm /tlb:nome_tlb.tlb nome_dll.dll

Agora é só usar nos projetos Delphi ou Magic XPA conforme os posts.

Abraços.