# Dll C# no Delphi 7

Tags: c#, .net, delphi, delphi-7, dll

Preciso gerar um arquivo *".ini"* na pasta *"C:\Windows\Temp\USB.ini"* contendo informações das impressoras instaladas para um outro programa pré-histórico consumir.
Criei a seguinte (gambiarra) dll em c# :

```
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None),     
     Guid("C92C5DDA-7766-4CBC-8141-6817DDE97B6F")]    
public class Solucoes 
{
    public Solucoes()
    {
    }

    public void getPrinters()
    {
        string line = "";
        string passaDireto = "";

        FileIOPermission f2 = new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.AllAccess, @"C:\Windows\Temp\");

        if (File.Exists(@"C:\Windows\Temp\USB.ini"))
        {
            System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\Windows\Temp\USB.ini");
            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if ((line.ToUpper().Contains("PASSADIRETO="))) passaDireto = line;
            }
            file.Close();
            File.Delete(@"C:\Windows\Temp\USB.ini");
        }
        File.Create(@"C:\Windows\Temp\USB.ini").Close();
        TextWriter arquivo = System.IO.File.AppendText(@"C:\Windows\Temp\USB.ini");
        arquivo.WriteLine("[Porta]");

        ManagementObjectSearcher printers = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * from Win32_Printer");
        foreach (ManagementObject item in printers.Get())
        {
            string print = "", port = "";
            if ((bool)item.GetPropertyValue("Shared"))
            {
                print = (string)item.GetPropertyValue("ShareName");
            }
            else print = (string)item.GetPropertyValue("Name");
            port = (string)item.GetPropertyValue("PortName");

            if (print.Length > 44) arquivo.WriteLine(string.Concat(print.Substring(0, 43), "=", port));
            else arquivo.WriteLine(string.Concat(print, "=", port));
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(passaDireto))
        {
            arquivo.WriteLine("[Opcoes]");
            arquivo.WriteLine(passaDireto);
        }
        arquivo.Close();                            
    }
}
```

Deixei a dll como COM visível e registrada também.
Para registrar eu usei `regasm.exe SolucoesClassLibrary.dll /tlb /codebase`

Criei a unit dela no Delphi 7 e tentei fazer a chamada:

```
var
    Impressora: ISolucoes;

begin
    Impressora.getPrinters();
end;
```

Quando eu executo ela lança essa exception bem na hora que chamo a rotina da dll feita em c#. `Exception EAccessViolation in module USB.exe at 0006B3BA. Access violation at address 0046B3BA in module 'USB.exe'. Read of address 000000 00.`

Alguém sabe me ajudar?

Comment: Configure a DLL para ser COM Visible, adicione a DLL como Controle ActiveX no Delphi

Comment: Já fiz isso, o problema é que não consigo chamar a função getInstalledPrinters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eu uso uma "receitinha de bolo" que sempre funciona para mim.

Segue:

Crie uma interface:

```
namespace EscreveINI
{
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual), Guid("80911B7A-608D-4A54-B51B-CF09E512CAD4")]
    public interface IEscreveIniClass
    {
        void Escrever();
    }
}
```

E uma classe:

```
namespace EscreveINI
{
    using System.IO;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None), Guid("C77906F8-59A9-4187-B818-2F6CABF1A2AF")]
    public class EscreveIniClass : IEscreveIniClass
    {
        public void Escrever()
        {
            File.Create(@"C:\Windows\Temp\USB.ini").Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Marque no Assembly Information do ClassLibrary a opção "Make assembly COM-Visible"

E no build marque a opção "Register for COM interop"

Após isso copie a DLL para o local desejado juntamente com o arquivo tlb e rode o comando o seguinte comando de registro:

```
set path="%path%";C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
regasm /tlb:EscreveINI.tlb EscreveINI.dll /codebase
```

Em seguida no Delphi vá em Project, Import Type Library e busque o tlb e clique em Create Unit.

Em seguida basta utilizar assim:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  lEscreveArquivo: IEscreveIniClass;
begin
  lEscreveArquivo := CoEscreveIniClass.Create();
  lEscreveArquivo.Escrever;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Um vez eu precisei trabalhar com XML do Delphi 5. Dai fiz uma dll em C# e criei uma unit no Delphi para servir de interface.

Vou dar um paste do código, é meio grande e tem muitas functions para chamar os metódos que foram criados na minha classe .Net

Eu basicamente carrego a dll e a mantenho em memória numa classe estática.
Pode ignorar 90% do código que é para manipular um array (de arrays) de strings e "simular" um pseudo xml.

Dá uma olhada na parte onde tem a ProgId da dll!

```
//****************************************************************************//
//***  Unit para servir de interface para                                  ***//
//***  a DLL útil implementada em .Net                                     ***//
//***                                                                      ***//
//***  28/04/2010                                                          ***//
//***  by Jean Charles Bulinckx                                            ***//
//****************************************************************************//
unit uUtil;

interface
uses
  ComObj, ComCtrls;

type
  // XML serializado retornado pela DLL
  tArrayNos = Array of Array of String;

  // estrutura que representa o XML DEsSerializado pelo Delphi
  tNo = class
     nome:String;
     valor:String;
     id:String;
     idPai:String;
     filhos:Array of tNo;
  end;

  tArrNo = Array of tNo;

  tUtil = class
  private
     // Mantém a DLL em memória
     DLL: Variant;
  public
     // Metódos que chamam a dll
     function Importar(servico, arquivo, login, senha: String):String;
     function LeXML(arquivo:String):tArrayNos;
     function Criptografar(dados:String; descriptar:Boolean):String;
     // Métodos para ler/montar árvore
     function EncontrarFilho(nome: String; raiz: tNo):tNo;
     function EncontrarFilhos(nome: String; raiz: tNo):tArrNo;
     function EncontrarRaiz(id: String; xml: tArrayNos):tNo;
     function MontarFilhos(raiz:tNo; xml: tArrayNos):tNo;
     function DeSerializarArvore(xml: tArrayNos):tNo;
     function ReSerializarArvore(no: tNo):tArrayNos;
  published
     Constructor Inicializar();
  end;

  // ProgId da DLL
Const
  NomeClasse:String = 'Xpto.Util';

implementation

function InstanciaClasse(strClasse: String):Variant;
begin
   result := CreateOleObject(strClasse);
end;

// Função que retorna uma instância da classe
Constructor tUtil.Inicializar();
begin
   inherited;
   self.DLL := InstanciaClasse(NomeClasse);
end;    

// ********************************
// *** Funções que chamam a DLL ***
// ********************************
function tUtil.Importar(servico, arquivo, login, senha: String):String;
begin
   result := self.DLL.ChamarWSB(servico,arquivo, login, senha, false);
end;

function tUtil.LeXML(arquivo:String):tArrayNos;
begin
   result := self.DLL.LerXML(arquivo);
end;

function tUtil.Criptografar(dados:String; descriptar:Boolean):String;
begin
   result := self.DLL.Criptografar(dados, descriptar);
end;
// ********************************
// *** Funções que chamam a DLL ***
// ********************************

// *****************************************************
// *** Funções para "ler" a árvore de nós (tags) xml ***
// *****************************************************

// Encontra o filho pelo nome
function tUtil.EncontrarFilho(nome: String; raiz: tNo):tNo;
var no:tNo;
 i:integer;
begin
   no := tNo.Create();
   for i := 0 to Length(raiz.filhos) - 1
   do begin
      if (raiz.filhos[i].nome = nome)
      then begin
         no := raiz.filhos[i];
      end;
   end;
   result := no;
end;

// Encontrar uma coleção de filhos pelo nome
function tUtil.EncontrarFilhos(nome: String; raiz: tNo):tArrNo;
var arrNo:tArrNo;
 i,l:integer;
begin
   for i := 0 to Length(raiz.filhos) - 1
   do begin
      if (raiz.filhos[i].nome = nome)
      then begin
         l := Length(arrNo);
         SetLength(arrNo,l+1);
         arrNo[l] := raiz.filhos[i];
      end;
   end;
   result := arrNo;
end;

// Acha quem é a raiz (quem não tem pai)
function tUtil.EncontrarRaiz(id: String; xml: tArrayNos):tNo;
var no:tNo;
 i:integer;
 id2:String;
begin
   no := tNo.Create();
   for i := 0 to Length(xml) - 1
   do begin
      id2 := xml[i,3];// id do pai
      if (id=id2)
      then begin
         no.nome := xml[i,0];
         no.valor := xml[i,1];
         no.id := xml[i,2];
         no.idPai := xml[i,3];
      end;
   end;
   result := no;
end;

// Monta um ramo de árvore recursivamente
function tUtil.MontarFilhos(raiz:tNo; xml: tArrayNos):tNo;
var
 no:tNo;
 i,l:integer;
 idPai:String;
begin
   for i := 0 to Length(xml) - 1
   do begin
      idPai := xml[i,3];//id do pai
      if (idPai = raiz.id)
      then begin
         no := tNo.Create();
         no.nome := xml[i,0];
         no.valor := xml[i,1];
         no.id := xml[i,2];
         no.idPai := xml[i,3];
         no := MontarFilhos(no,xml);
         l:=Length(raiz.filhos);
         SetLength(raiz.filhos,l+1);
         raiz.filhos[l]:=no;
      end;
   end;
   result := raiz;
end;

// Remonta numa estrutura em memória o .XML serializado pela DLL
function tUtil.DeSerializarArvore(xml: tArrayNos):tNo;
var raiz:tNo;
begin
   raiz := EncontrarRaiz('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000', xml);

   // Monta os filhos recursivamente
   raiz := MontarFilhos(raiz, xml);

   // Retorna a árvore em memória
   result := raiz;
end;

// ReSerializa uma árvore para um Array of Arrays of String
function tUtil.ReSerializarArvore(no: tNo):tArrayNos;
var xml,ramo:tArrayNos;
i,j,lenPai,lenFilho,lenNeto:integer;
begin
   ramo := nil;
   if no <> nil
   then begin
      SetLength(xml,1,4);
      xml[0,0] := no.nome;
      xml[0,1] := no.valor;
      xml[0,2] := no.id;
      xml[0,3] := no.idPai;
      // recursão
      lenFilho := Length(no.Filhos);
      for i := 0 to lenFilho - 1
      do begin
         ramo := ReSerializarArvore(no.Filhos[i]);
         lenNeto := Length(ramo);
         lenPai := Length(xml);
         SetLength(xml,lenPai+lenNeto,4);
         for j := 0 to lenNeto - 1
         do begin
            xml[lenPai + j] := ramo[j];
         end
      end
   end;
   result := xml;
end;
// *****************************************************
// *** Funções para "ler" a árvore de nós (tags) xml ***
// *****************************************************
end.
```