# Criar dll em C# e utilizar em Delphi 7

Tags: c#, delphi, delphi-7, dll

Estou precisando criar uma dll em C# para que possa utiliza-la em delphi.

**Tentei o seguinte:**

Criei uma dll básica com um método de soma, porém ao chamá-la no delphi não retorna nada, seria como o método criado não existisse.

Abaixo o código em C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ClasseCom
{
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    public class soma        
    {
        public soma() { }
        public double somar(int a, int b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }

    }
}
```

Aqui como tento chama-la no Delphi 7:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Handle : THandle;
  somar : TSomaDll;
  total : Double;

begin

  Handle:=LoadLibrary ('ClasseCom.dll');
  if Handle <> 0 then begin

    @somar:=GetProcAddress(Handle, 'somar');

    if @somar <> nil then
      total := somar(1, 2);

    FreeLibrary (Handle);

  end;

  ShowMessage(FloatToStr(total));

end;
```

No Delphi a variável `@soma` esta retornando como `nil`.

Também Utilizei um aplicativo chamado DDL Export Viewer que mostra os métodos da dll, porém para a minha não apresenta nada, e tentando a de validação da Inscrição Estadual fornecido pelo sintegra apresenta o método da mesma.

Comment: Uma DLL do .Net não é padrão, então não conseguirá desta forma. Deve ter um jeito de fazer isso, eu até tenho algumas ideias, mas não vou arriscar por não ter experiência e sólido conhecimento com isso.

Comment: Ariel, temo uma pergunta com basicamente o mesmo título http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8107/5846

Comment: A solução é declarar as classes no C# como [ComVisible](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comvisibleattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) e consumir no Delphi como ActiveX em vez de DLL Windows. O Delphi é muito bom em importar objetos ActiveX, gerar wrappers pra eles e gerenciar o ciclo de vida, bem bacana. Trabalhei em muitos projetos assim. Infelizmente não tenho acesso agora a nenhum código que possa render uma resposta, mas vá por esse caminho que você não vai se arrepender: ComVisible no C# e consumo como ActiveX no Delphi. Deve haver exemplos na net. Boa sorte!

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/47254/com-interop-com-client-e-server/47328#47328

Answer (score 2):

Já tive que fazer essa integração do C# e o delphi e bati muito com a cabeça rsrs..

Bom no seu C#, você instala via nuget o [UnmanagedExports](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UnmanagedExports)

E no seu C# marque com o atributo DllExport o método que você quer que o delphi "enxerge".

Marque sua classe também com `[ComVisible(true)]` e define um Guid

Seu projeto deve estar configurado para compilar na plataforma x86.

Por exemplo:

```
[Guid("14fd1190-df04-488c-ab0f-b120ea3e3f3a")]
[ComVisible(true)]
public class Exported
{

    [DllExport]
    public static int func(int a, int b) 
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA); //é necessario se você quiser que o delphi abra um form do C#

        Form1 f = new Form1();
        f.ShowDialog();

        return a + b;
    }
}
```

E no seu delphi declara a function, referenciado dll, lembrando que dll deve estar no mesmo diretório que a sua aplicação (.exe) do delphi..

```
function func(var a: Integer, var b: Integer ): Integer; stdcall; external suaDllEmCSharp.dll;
```

e durante seu codigo basta chamar

```
...
if func(1,2)=3 then
...
```

Lembro que tentei fazer para carregar a dll em tempo de execução, como você fez, mas não obtive sucesso.

Tive que fazer a declaração estática.

Espero ter ajudado...

Answer (score 2):

Com já foi dito anteriormente o caminho é você consumir o *assembly* como COM:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ClasseCom
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [ComDefaultInterface(typeof(ISoma))]
    [Guid("E8D53EED-3B2F-45A8-BB29-CC111BB426D1")]
    public class Soma : ISoma
    {
        public double Somar(int a, int b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }
    }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("97D1968E-DC7F-45BD-BD0E-1AC822D95264")]
    public interface ISoma
    {
        double Somar(int a, int b);
    }
}
```

Com isso você vai ter sua classe exposta via COM. A partir daí você usa o utilitário tlbexp pra exportar o tlb do seu *assembly*:

```
tlbexp.exe Caminho\Do\Seu\Assembly\AssemblyDaClasseCOM.dll
```

A maneira mais fácil de acessar o utilitário (assumindo que você tenha o Visual Studio instalado) é através *prompt* de comando de desenvolvedor do Visual Studio (Developer Command Prompt) que pode ser encontrado dentro da pasta do Visual Studio no menu Iniciar.

Depois de gerar o tlb usando o **tlbexp** é só importar ele no Delphi como você faria com um ActiveX qualquer. Como foi dito pelo @Caffé o importador do Delphi vai gerar *wrappers* para essas classes COM que vão te ajudar muito.

Um ponto importante a ser lembrado nesse momento é que pra utilizar você vai ter que ter esse assembly .NET registrado na sua máquina, usando o utilitário [Regasm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzat5yw6(v=vs.110).aspx)

Caso queira usar sem registro (o que eu recomendo fortemente pra evitar o famoso DLL Hell) você pode dar uma olhada neste artigo: [Com Registration Free](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eew13bza(v=vs.110).aspx)

É isso, qualquer dúvida é só falar.

## Edit

Código de exemplo em Delphi (Funcionando):

```
uses
  MeuComponenteCom_TLB;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  LSoma: ISoma;
  LResultado: Double;
begin
    LSoma := CoSoma.Create;
    LResultado := LSoma.Somar(1, 2);

    ShowMessage(FloatToStr(LResultado));
end;

end.
```

**Obs.:** O exemplo foi feito usando do Delphi XE7.

## Edit2

Caso tenha dúvida sobre como adicionar um TLB seguem algumas imagens que mostram onde você pode fazer isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]